# "Bizarre" continued fraction of Ramanujan! But where's the proof?

Tags: recreational-mathematics, exponential-function, pi, continued-fractions

> $$\frac{e^\pi-1}{e^\pi+1}=\cfrac\pi{2+\cfrac{\pi^2}{6+\cfrac{\pi^2}{10+\cfrac{\pi^2}{14+...}}}}$$

"Bizarre" continued fraction of Ramanujan! But where's the proof? i have no training in continued fractions so i have no idea how to attempt to prove it.

Comment: I think this one follows from a more general identity obtained by replacing $\pi$ with $x$.

Comment: @MJD which one?

Comment: If you replace $\pi$ with $x$ in the identity you are asking about, I think the resulting identity is true for all $x$.

Comment: @MJD yes, but can you reference the general identity you meant (and a proof if possible)?

Comment: See [Gauss's continued fraction: Applications](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss's_continued_fraction#Applications). The general statement is based on the study of [hypergeometric functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function).

Comment: See [here](http://paramanands.blogspot.in/2011/04/continued-fraction-expansion-of-tanx.html#.VKmJLPmUdYY) for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The left hand side is  $ \tanh \frac{\pi}{2} $ so it may be worth looking at a continued fraction for $ \tanh x $. It looks like a special case of Gauss's continued fraction (I can't link to it directly but there is a Wikipedia page on it). Also, Ramanujan is not mentioned.

Answer (score 6):

(*Not an answer but too long for a comment.*) Here is another "bizarre" one involving $e$ and $\pi$ (correcting a typo spotted by Paramanand Singh),

$$\sqrt{\frac{\pi\,e^x}{2x}}=1+\frac{x}{1\cdot3}+\frac{x^2}{1\cdot3\cdot5}+\frac{x^3}{1\cdot3\cdot5\cdot7}+\dots+\cfrac1{\color{blue}x+\cfrac{1}{\color{blue}1+\cfrac{2}{\color{blue}x+\cfrac{3}{\color{blue}1+\ddots}}}}$$

for $x>0$. No need to mention who found this. As Kevin Brown of *Mathpages* commented in this old [sci.math post](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/sci.math/UrnIEEldJv4/c5_R8XGrANUJ), *"Is there any other mathematician whose work is instantly recognizable?"*

Comment: wow very surprising indeed !! thnx for sharing = )

Comment: For $x = 1$ this is proved at http://paramanands.blogspot.com/2014/06/a-continued-fraction-for-error-function-by-ramanujan.html

Comment: BTW do you have a proof for the above formula for general $x$? Or is it possible to get this from the development done in my blog post?

Comment: It can be easily seen that $$g(x) = 1 + \frac{x}{1\cdot 3} + \cdots$$ is given by $$g(x) = \sqrt{\frac{\pi e^{x}}{2x}} - \sqrt{\frac{e^{x}}{x}}\int_{\sqrt{x}}^{\infty}e^{-t^{2}/2}\,dt$$ and we know that $$\phi(x) = e^{x^{2}/2}\int_{x}^{\infty}e^{-t^{2}/2}\,dt = \frac{1}{x +}\frac{1}{x +}\frac{2}{x +}\frac{3}{x + \cdots}$$ therefore $$g(x) = \sqrt{\frac{\pi e^{x}}{2x}} - \frac{\phi(\sqrt{x})}{\sqrt{x}}$$ and if we do calculations it should come out as $$\frac{\phi(\sqrt{x})}{\sqrt{x}} = \frac{1}{x+}\frac{1}{1 +}\frac{2}{x +}\frac{3}{1 +}\frac{4}{x + \cdots}$$

Comment: @ParamanandSingh: Sorry, no proof. I just found this in Ramanujan's Notebooks. And we know Ramanujan didn't bother with proofs.  :)

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII: I have tried to derive it on the basis of formulas in my blog post. I think that the continued fraction should be as in my comment (i.e. the denominators should have pattern $x, 1, x, 1, x, 1$ instead of $1, x, 1, x, 1, x$ as you mention in your post.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh: I checked my copy of Berndt's _Ramanujan's Notebooks Vol II, Chap 12, Entry 43_, and you're right. (To be sure, I also checked it with _Mathematica_.) I'll edit the post.